# JHipster i18n for entity not being used

Tags: internationalization, jhipster

I have a a JHipster application and I can see that the UI has all the field labels ok as some sort of defaults. But I also see that the entity specific translations are not being used.

I have a file `src/main/webapp/i18n/en/employee.json` for example,

```
{
  "myApp": {
    "employee": {
      "home": {
        "title": "Employees",
        "createLabel": "Create a new Employee TEST TEST",
        "createOrEditLabel": "Create or edit an Employee",
        "notFound": "No Employees found"
      },
      "created": "A new Employee is created with identifier {{ param }}",
      "updated": "An Employee is updated with identifier TEST TEST {{ param }}",
      "deleted": "An Employee is deleted with identifier {{ param }}",
      "delete": {
        "question": "Are you sure you want to delete Employee {{ id }}?"
      },
      "detail": {
        "title": "Employee"
      },
      "Employee": "Employee",
    }
  }
}
```

The create label just says "Create a new Employee", not "Create a new Employee TEST TEST".

Also, when I save an entity, I am seeing `translation-not-found[A employee is updated with identifier 1]`

---

Adding information suggested to [Gaël Marziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou).

1. Does it work when you restart webpack dev server npm start?

   1. I start my server. In a terminal, I do `npm start`.

      ```
      Webpack: Finished after 35.767 seconds.
      DONE  Compiled successfully in 35797ms                                                                                                                                                                                      12:50:47 PM
      No type errors found
      Version: typescript 3.4.5
      ```
   2. Same error: `translation-not-found[A employee is updated with identifier 1]`.
2. What are the keys in your HTML templates?

   1. There is a file `employee.component.html` and it uses keys:

      ```
      myApp.employee.home.title
      myApp.employee.home.createLabel
      myApp.employee.home.notFound
      global.field.id
      myApp.employee.name
      entity.action.view
      entity.action.edit
      entity.action.delete
      ```

      but in no file so I see the use of `myApp.employee.updated` - a key that I also added "TEST TEST" to.
3. Which version of JHipster?

   1. `jhipsterVersion "6.7.1"`

Comment: Does it work when you restart webpack dev server `npm start`? What are the keys in your HTML templates? Which version of JHipster?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I added extra data, but not sure what you meant by "keys in your HTML templates"? Is that an entity specific HTML file?

Comment: i18n keys that you use in your template within jhiTranslate directive like in `jhiTranslate="home.title"`. In short, please show an extract of your template where you use the failing message. Maybe this does occur only in alert messages?

Comment: Ok, found those - but I don't see `myApp.employee.updated` anywhere - the key that I would expect to be used for the message when I update one of these entities.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason. In `EmployeeResource`, the `updateEmployee` was calling a version of `createEntityUpdateAlert` that just sends a message, not a key.

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, employee.getId().toString()))
    .body(result);
```

Obviously, client side only expected a key and threw an error..

I need to change that to the version that sends a key.

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, employee.getId().toString()))
    .body(result);
```